# How can i utilize Azure backup service to backup multiple laptop/desktops

Tags: azure, cloud, backup, remote-backup

I have used Azure backup service to backup single laptop/desktop over the WAN. However what if I have 100 laptop to be backed-up.

Have someone used Azure backup service to protect multiple laptop and desktops?

Answer (score 1):

there are a couple of components that come with Azure backup, each of them has a specific use case as below:

1- Azure Backup (MARS) agent
Back up files and folders on physical or virtual Windows OS (VMs can be on-premises or in Azure)
No separate backup server required.

2- System Center DPM
Application-aware snapshots (VSS)
Full flexibility for when to take backups
Recovery granularity (all)
Can use Recovery Services vault
Linux support on Hyper-V and VMware VMs
Back up and restore VMware VMs using DPM 2012 R2

3- Azure Backup Server
App aware snapshots (VSS)
Full flexibility for when to take backups
Recovery granularity (all)
Can use Recovery Services vault
Linux support on Hyper-V and VMware VMs
Back up and restore VMware VMs
Does not require a System Center license

4-Azure IaaS VM Backup
Native backups for Windows/Linux
No specific agent installation required
Fabric-level backup with no backup infrastructure needed

For full info regarding **Which Azure Backup components should I use?**: checkout the following link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-introduction-to-azure-backup

as suggested by @Vikranth S, MARS would be your best option for the use case you've described.

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

There are two azure backup products which can be used to backup on-premises workloads.

1. [Using Microsoft Azure Recovery services agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup) (MARS)

2.[Using Microsoft Azure Backup server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/tutorial-backup-windows-server-to-azure) (MABS)

With MARS agent you can protect Files & Folders and System State of only Windows clients and server operating system, but you have to manually register each and every server with recovery services vault.

With MABs you can protect entire (Windows and Linux) Machines, if you register one server with recovery services vault, you can protect all other Machines are in same network by using that server. With MABS you can only protect Server operating system starting from Win 2008 R2. Please let me know if you  have any other queries